# Send an adaptive card through Microsoft Graph API - Error when getting Submit Action

Tags: spring-boot, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I am able to send buttons and hyperlinks using the below JSON, but whenever I am clicking on the button getting an error.[image]

API URL - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats/chatId/messages
JSON Request:

````
    "body": {
        "contentType": "html",
        "content": "<attachment id=\"74d20c7f34aa4a7fb74e2b30004247c5\"></attachment>"
    },
    "attachments": [
        {
            "id": "74d20c7f34aa4a7fb74e2b30004247c5",
            "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.thumbnail",
            "contentUrl": null,
            "content": "{\r\n  \"title\": \"This is an example of posting a card\",\r\n  \"subtitle\": \"<h3>This is the subtitle</h3>\",\r\n  \"text\": \"Here is some body text. <br>\\r\\nAnd a <a href=\\\"http://microsoft.com/\\\">hyperlink</a>. <br>\\r\\nAnd below that is some buttons:\",\r\n  \"buttons\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"type\": \"messageBack\",\r\n      \"title\": \"Login to FakeBot\",\r\n      \"text\": \"login\",\r\n      \"displayText\": \"login\",\r\n      \"value\": \"login\"\r\n    }\r\n  ]\r\n}",
        }
    ]
}```
````

Comment: It doesn't seem to be feasible to handle button event through graph API. If you want to handle button event then you can send message/card through bot.

Comment: I can't test in my side but per my searching, it should be ok to send card with button via a n http request. You may refer to [this graph api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java#request-2) to check the details.

Comment: Yes, you can send card with action buttons using http request. But button actions except Action.OpenUrl won't function here using delegated permissions.

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT - Yes, I was able to send different types of cards containing buttons, but only Action.Url was working. It is working through a bot but our use case is to use Graph API and get the action performed by user bak to our service.

Comment: @TinyWang - I was using the same example but when the user clicks on the button it throws an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be feasible to handle button event through graph API. If you want to handle button event then you can send message/card through bot.
You can send card with action buttons using HTTP request. But button actions except Action.OpenUrl will not support here.